# Sticky header breaks when its height is made responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to implement a sticky header like [this one](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sticky_header), but *responsive*.

I've got it mostly working, except for one part: the page content below the header **jumps up suddenly** when the page is scrolled back up.

I'm using JavaScript and jQuery.

I've marked where I suspect the problem to be with a comment:

```
<script>
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var top_cont = document.getElementById("top-container");

function myFunction() {
    var sticky = top_cont.offsetHeight;
    var pad_amt = header.offsetHeight+"px";

    if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
        $(".content").css({"padding-top": pad_amt}); // I think how or when this is being calculated is the main problem
        header.classList.add("sticky");
    } else {
        header.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
}
</script>
```

Here is the whole page as a snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
 margin: 0;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#top-container {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: space-between;
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
 padding: 1px;
 text-align: center;
 height: 14vw;
}
#top-container *,
.header * {
 margin: 0;
}

.header {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 background: #555;
 color: #f1f1f1;
 height: 12vw;
}

.content {
 padding: 16px;
 padding-top: 0px;
}

.sticky {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
}

</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="top-container">
 <h1>Scroll Down</h1>
 <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>

<div class="header" id="myHeader">
 <h2>My Header</h2>
</div>

<div class="content">
 <h3>On Scroll Sticky Header</h3>
 <p>The header will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
 <p>Scroll back up to remove the sticky effect.</p>
 <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
 <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
 <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
 <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p><p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p> <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p><p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p> <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p><p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p> <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p><p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
 <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
 <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
 <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
 <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>

<script>
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};
 
var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var top_cont = document.getElementById("top-container");

function myFunction() {
 var sticky = top_cont.offsetHeight;
 var pad_amt = header.offsetHeight+"px";
 
 if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
  $(".content").css({"padding-top": pad_amt}); // I think how or when this is being calculated is the main problem
  header.classList.add("sticky");
 } else {
  header.classList.remove("sticky");
 }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The header is sticking at the top of the page regardless of browser window size (and consequently changing header size) - this is good. Just need to get it to adjust the content `padding-top` correctly.

### Support requirements:

IE 11, Edge, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera, iOS Safari, Android Browser, Chrome for Android

Comment: Are you not allowed to use position: sticky?

Comment: My completely subjective, personal recommendation would be to not use w3schools. In my completely subjective personal opinion I by no means want to force on anyone, that site needs to die as fast as possible.

Comment: @DoğancanArabacı Unfortunately I still need to support [IE11](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky), so... no.  :-(

Comment: @ChrisG I realize a lot of people despise w3schools (I don't understand why), and I know others like them. Personally I've found them helpful, and I know of no site that can be a replacement for me. Stack Overflow, CSS-Tricks, and w3schools are my top-3 references and each are helpful in different ways. While I respect your advice, I don't see how I can take it until some competition comes along and does better than w3schools. Thanks for your opinion - now let's not let this comment section get off-topic. :-)

Comment: Since you mentioned not knowing a better one, try this one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem as far as I can tell is that IE11 complains about `$` being undefined, which breaks the JS code.
**Edit:** I just realized that was from High security settings from a previous test; the jQuery version will work fine with a Medium security level

Here's a solution without jQuery, tested and working on IE11, Firefox and Chrome for Android:

```
window.onscroll = myFunction;

var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var top_cont = document.getElementById("top-container");

var oldOffset = 0;

function myFunction() {
    var sticky = top_cont.offsetHeight;
    var pad_amt = header.offsetHeight + "px";

    var offset = window.pageYOffset;

    // scrolling down
    if (offset > oldOffset) {
        if (offset > sticky) {
            document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0].style.paddingTop = pad_amt;
            header.classList.add("sticky");
        }
    }
    // scrolling up
    else {
        if (offset < sticky) {
            document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0].style.paddingTop = 0;
            header.classList.remove("sticky");
        }
    }

    oldOffset = offset;
}
```

I'm tracking the direction of the scroll because when I scrolled slowly past the threshold in IE, the padding would make the page flicker between the two states.

Comment: I just tested on my virtual machine - works perfectly even in IE. Thank you! (Yes, I struggled with the directional issue you mentioned.) The security level testing info is helpful. How can I avoid the $ undefined problem in the future?

Comment: Not sure, but you could use a local copy of jQuery maybe, instead of loading it off the CDN? A high security level blocks all JS, so most users probably don't have that setting, but if they do, there's nothing you can do but show them a "don't use IE" message.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use javaScript for sticky header you can do that using plain css `position:sticky`

Here is the fiddle using `position:sticky`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#top-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 14vw;
}

#top-container *,
.header * {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #555;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 12vw;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="top-container">
    <h1>Scroll Down</h1>
    <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="header" id="myHeader">
    <h2>My Header</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <h3>On Scroll Sticky Header</h3>
    <p>The header will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
    <p>Scroll back up to remove the sticky effect.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Using Jquery:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 140) {
    $('.header').addClass('sticky');
  } else {
    $('.header').removeClass('sticky');
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    
    #top-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-between;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      padding: 1px;
      text-align: center;
      height: 14vw;
    }
    
    #top-container *,
    .header * {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .header {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      background: #555;
      color: #f1f1f1;
      height: 12vw;
    }
    
    .content {
      padding: 16px;
      padding-top: 0px;
    }
    
    .sticky {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0px;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="top-container">
    <h1>Scroll Down</h1>
    <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="header" id="myHeader">
    <h2>My Header</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <h3>On Scroll Sticky Header</h3>
    <p>The header will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
    <p>Scroll back up to remove the sticky effect.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I really want to use this as it is (CSS-only!), but unfortunately since [IE11 doesn't support position:sticky](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky) I'm afraid we need to think around that limitation. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm adding the IE-support requirement to my question (sorry I didn't realize at the time). And here's an upvote for the time being.  ;-)

Comment: I usually try to avoid polyfills, but do you think [Stickyfill](https://github.com/wilddeer/stickyfill) might be a good solution?

Comment: I think plain jquery or javascript is better than polyfills...because polyfills also uses javascript. so no use